# Building animation in Android app

Tags: android, animation

I have done apps which uses only pictures and sound clips. What I want to do is to build an Android app which involves animation. I have seen many of the "Water effect" apps in play store, which has quite good animation effect. One of my them is "Koi Pond". I would like to do the similar kind of app for sand. The detailing of the animation should look good as we see and touch the real sand.
 I'm new to animation stuff and have no idea about it. Can anyone please help me out with how to use the detailed animation for Android?  I know that it is not possible only with java. Please refer me to any blogs/docs available on this stuff.
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such effects (as used in Koi Pond) you will need several pixel shaders. To use it you will need to us OpenGL ES 2.0. I would recommend using a game engine like AndEngine for the basic setup and the shader usage. If you have no experience with shaders it won't be that easy!

I'm not sure if AndEngine is the best choice for that, but it is possible with it.
Check it out http://www.andengine.org/

There are also a couple of shader tutorials in the forum

Answer (score 1):

At first for translate or some other simple animation you can use android native animation method , but for great things you can use , [this](http://gstreamer.com/) , I think it's all you want ;)

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan